# Getting Unmarshalling unknown type code when parcel same object again

Tags: android, android-activity, parcelable

I have a circular activity workflow like

A -> B -> C -> A -> B -> C -> A -> B -> C...

I'm passing a Parcelable from activit B to C. The first time it works. The second time it gives me

> Parcel android.os.Parcel@405156d0: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7471204 at offset 1108

In the line reading the object.

The object didn't change. I don't know if it's exactly the same instance, but the contents at least are exactly the same. Why it works the first time and it doesn't work the second time?

Sometimes it also happens the first time.

I tried removing everything in writing / reading (testing with only one integer field), and still get the same.

When the error comes the object **isn't read at all**, the line with `getParcelable()` is executed but it never executes `createFromParcel` or further the contructor. It just gives error and does nothing. So it's not an error with the parcelation of the fields.

I'm completly clueless...

I tried reproducing with a very small test environment - 2 activities and a very small object there I can pass the parcelable as many times as I want and it's correct.

I can't post here my entire code.

I only want to know which kind of things can be causing this error. The `writeToParcel` and the constructor are correct, data is written and read in the same order, correct tpyes, there's also the CREATOR variable which is also correct, I checked everything 100 times. And as said it works lot of times. Sometimes the data in the object is exactly the same (checked, every field contains the same value), first time it works, second time it shows this "Unmarshalling unknown type".

Another thing which is quite interesting and could be related, and I also don't understand, is that the parcelable, although I execute `putExtra` only one time, is being written twice. I put logs and it's sure `putExtra` is executed only once. But the `writeToParcel` is executed twice... no idea why. In the simplified example this doesn't happen.

Any hint is welcome. I did all the work to pass my parameters everywhere using Parcelable, and they're a lot, because everybody says "I highly encourage to use Parcelable instead", you say your teeth are bleeding and get "use Parcelable". Now I'm using Parcelable and all I got is a new bunch of problems.

Comment: I think it is unlikely that you will get any bites on this question. You've basically said that you're sure you've done everything absolutely correctly but it doesn't work. You also haven't posted any code (even just a little bit). What is it you want us to tell you?

Comment: The meaning of that error, or possible things causing it. Also if somebody had related experiences he will recognize them without code... but yeah, when I have time I'll reduce my code to the neccessary to show this and copy here, maybe it helps to get the interest of other target groups :)

Comment: The meaning of that error is that your Parcel is corrupted. That means either that your readers/writers don't match or that you've somehow added other junk to the Parcel. But based on your other comments (methods being called twice when they shouldn't, etc.) it looks like you've got other problems. Maybe you've got a threading problem (multiple threads accessing the same data in an unsynchronized way)? No way to know without more information.

Comment: So, I want to give this question a shot because I just go this error cleared on my code. Do you remember if you were trying to `getExtra` in the `onCreate` method of your activity?

Comment: hey @Spencer , @Ixx.  I have the same problem, and as @Spencer said, yeah I do this in `onCreate()`. Any solution, advices?

Comment: Same problem. how do do solve this problem lxxm, Spencer, Ovidiu Latcu?

Answer (score 0):

I Got this error when I was using a Parcelable class, & I added a variable in this class & forgot to add this variable to the methods "writeToParcel" and the constructor with the Parcel object

It was solved by adding this variable to the below methods.

```
@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeString(name);

}

public ItemDetails(Parcel source) {
        id = source.readString();
        name = source.readString();
}
```